# creating newcommand on my own package

Tags: macros, packages

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, but can't find what exactly.

Writing my thesis I created a package for my constants, they work OK:

```
\def \earthRadius {\num{6.371e6}\si{\metre}}
\def \lightSpeed {\num{2.99793e8}\si{\metre\per\second}}
\def \lightSpeedAprox {\num{3e8}\si{\metre\per\second}}
```

I have \num set to scientific by default, but stylewise I needed to add some decimal numbers at some places. So I decided to add a newcomand such as:

```
\newcommand{\thanum}[1]{\num[scientific-notation=false]{#1}}
```

The point is: I would like to put it in my package with the rest of my macros, but \latex doesn't seem to like it.
If I use the same command in the main file it works ok, but when I do it on the package it says:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \thanum already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.9 ...um}[1]{\num[scientific-notation=false]{#1}}
```

Same error both using TeXworks and ShareLatex. My approach for portability right now is to declare blank macros at the main.tex and renewcommand them on the package. It works, but I feel like the whole macro should be encapsulated on the package. What am I doing wrong?

---

I made a public project in sharelatex editable with the issue replicated: https://www.sharelatex.com/project/551003850f9d21382c0e5437

Comment: Not relevant to the question directly, but if you want a number and a unit you want `\SI`, _e.g._ `\SI{6.371e6}{\metre}`.

Comment: `\thanum` is defined by something else: you'll need to track it down and either choose another name or over-write it with `\renewcommand`.

Comment: No, it's not defined by something else. As I said, when defined on the main.tex file it works OK. Changing the name to a random sequence has exactly the same result (at the beginning I had the issue with \numDEC which I considered might be declared... but it's not)

Comment: just tried again with a Random name so you can see:

`LaTeX Error: Command \thaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbboioioioioioioioioioioioi already defined.

               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.9 ...oi}[1]{\num[scientific-notation=false]{#1}}
                                                  
....`

Comment: We need a proper minimal example we can compile to reproduce the error. There is simply no problem using `\newcommand` in a package. So something is wrong we've not seen and that something should be here and not somewhere in a project somewhere else. It can be tedious to create a minimal example. But it is often simply essential to diagnose problems correctly.

Comment: Totally Agree, I added on the Question a test project with the issue in sharelatex. I made it publicly editable.

Comment: It is a great example ;). But it should be *here*. Or do you plan to keep the problematic example there in perpetuity? (Or at least for the life of TeX SE.)

Answer (score 4):

Do check and see if `\thanum` is inadertently being defined twice.

And, as Joseph Wright has already noted in a comment, you should be using `\SI` rather than `\num` and `\si` individually when typesetting combined numbers and units.

Also, consider using `\newcommand` rather than `\def` to define the shorthand macros. That way, you can define the macros to take an *optional argument* which, by default, is unused or empty. Doing so makes it easy, if necessary, to override some of the formatting settings "on the fly".

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcommand\earthRadius[1][]{%
    \SI[tight-spacing,#1]
    {6.371e6}{\metre}}
\newcommand\lightSpeed[1][]{%
    \SI[tight-spacing,per-mode=symbol,group-digits=false,#1]
    {2.99793e8}{\metre\per\second}}
\newcommand\lightSpeedApprox[1][]{%
    \SI[tight-spacing,per-mode=symbol,#1]
    {3e8}{\metre\per\second}}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\earthRadius      & \earthRadius[tight-spacing=false]\\
\lightSpeed       & \lightSpeed[group-digits=true]\\
\lightSpeedApprox & \lightSpeedApprox[per-mode=reciprocal]\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Totally agree, the issue is.... I cannot use \newcommand on an external package.

Answer (score 3):

Please do not post links to external sites rather than constructing a proper minimal example. It makes it harder to help and renders your question of almost no value to future users with exactly similar problems.

The problem is that your main `.tex` file includes these lines

```
\input{thabeatmacros.sty}
\usepackage{thabeatmacros}
```

The `\input` reads your package file and processes its content. It creates the commands etc.

Then you load the package which inputs the file again and processes its content a second time. This tries to create the already existing commands again. Naturally, the names are already taken and LaTeX refuses to overwrite existing commands when you have told it they are new.

The solution is to simply remove the first line. Packages should never be `\input` in that way. You should always use `\usepackage{}`.

```
\usepackage{thabeatmacros}
```

Note also that the redefinition command is `\renewcommand` and not `\rewnewcommand`. However, that is obviously not what you want here anyway.

Thus:

```
\begin{filecontents}{thabeatmacros.sty}
\ProvidesPackage{thabeatmacros}[2016/02/23 v1.0 My own macros]

\newcommand* \earthRadius {\SI{6.371e6}{\metre}}
\newcommand* \lightSpeed {\SI{2.99793e8}{\metre\per\second}}
\newcommand* \lightSpeedAprox {\SI{3e8}{\metre\per\second}}
\newcommand*{\thanum}[1]{\num[scientific-notation=false]{#1}}

\endinput
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{thabeatmacros}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

There is a theory which states that if ever anyone discovers exactly what the Universe is for and why it is here, it will instantly disappear and be replaced by something even more bizarre and inexplicable.
There is another theory which states that this has already happened.

\subsection*{TESTING DEFs WORK}

\begin{itemize}
  \item {\huge\earthRadius\par}
  \item {\huge\lightSpeed\par}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image: fixed macros]

Comment: Thanks! I don't really know why I was doing the input... I guess I read it somewhere...